# SWAP usage too high after upgrading RAM

Tags: 20.04, ram, memory-usage

I had upgraded the ram on my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS from 16 GB to 32 GB. Things seemed to had worked fine, i.e., the machine ran and `cat /proc/meminfo` showed 32 GB of ram. Today the machine seemed considerably slower, so I checked again and this is what `top` looked like:

```
top - 14:00:38 up 17 days, 18:39,  1 user,  load average: 2.75, 2.39, 2.28
Tasks: 510 total,   2 running, 507 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 11.6 us,  1.8 sy,  0.1 ni, 86.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  31954.0 total,   1612.3 free,  13689.8 used,  16652.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,    368.6 free,   1679.4 used.  17463.2 avail Mem
```

Why is only 1612.3 M free, when the total is 31954 and 13689 is used? Do I need to reinstall Ubuntu after upgrading the ram?

If it helps, here's the latest `cat /proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:       32720944 kB
MemFree:         1527484 kB
MemAvailable:   17764224 kB
Buffers:         1158432 kB
Cached:         15098500 kB
SwapCached:        42640 kB
Active:         17130404 kB
Inactive:       11875732 kB
Active(anon):   11796372 kB
Inactive(anon):  1297452 kB
Active(file):    5334032 kB
Inactive(file): 10578280 kB
Unevictable:         596 kB
Mlocked:             580 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:         377668 kB
Dirty:             18900 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      12706816 kB
Mapped:          3533448 kB
Shmem:            353120 kB
KReclaimable:     796040 kB
Slab:            1239524 kB
SReclaimable:     796040 kB
SUnreclaim:       443484 kB
KernelStack:       31520 kB
PageTables:       107500 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    18457620 kB
Committed_AS:   35499648 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       92868 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:            17536 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     65536 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:    16035156 kB
DirectMap2M:    17354752 kB
DirectMap1G:     1048576 kB
```

Comment: Use "top" to see which processes consume the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you're doing great.

You have 17.7GB in Available Memory.

Linux uses all the non used memory to optimize IO, so for buffers/cache, this doesn't mean that your system does not have available memory.

So you have: 32GB in total, free 1.6GB, used by apps 13.6GB and 16.6GB in buffers/cached. Most of the buffers/cache can be used by the system when needed. The memory that really can be used is the MemAvailable, which is displayed as 17.7GB.

Run commands like:

```
free -h
```

For more clarity.

I think your problem is you have the default Swappiness value, 60, so the swap will be started to be used when you reach approximately 60% of RAM memory in use.

You can check this value with:

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Using swap normally is slow, cause accessing the drives is much more slower.

In my cloud systems and workstations I don't use swap, and if I use for whatever reason I set swappiness to values 1 or 10.

To do it until you restart the computer you can set this Kernel parameter by doing:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

You can then disable swap and enable it again.

```
sudo swapoff
```

and reenable again

```
sudo swapon -a
```

Your computer will fly again. :)

Cheers

Comment: I have seen more "high memory utilization" in RedHat based distros, and far fewer in Debian (Ubuntu) ones.

I think that you're really using that memory.  You may want to follow top a bit more during a "typical" session on your machine and see whether certain programs are taking up more memory than before.  I am speculating that  "greedy" programs want to grab a certain percentage of your available memory and may not release it or clean up afterwards.

Comment: With RedHat based distros it often looks like less memory available because of how it caches it.  This perception is less common in my Ubuntu installations.
I think that you're really using that memory. You maty want to follow top a bit more during a "typical" session on your machine and see whether certain programs are taking up more memory than before.  I am speculating that  "greedy" programs want to grab a certain percentage of your available memory and may not release it or clean up afterwards. Also, close top when you don't need it.